# Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: Could not find layout resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have faced a problem when creating project in Android Studio 2.2

When trying to create xml layout, I get following error:

**Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: Could not find layout resource**

[image]

Here is my xml code snippet :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
     <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent"                                     android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing ? and what is the layout resource ? Are you trying to include layout inside ?

Comment: Try to refresh but it doesn't work. App bar is the layout resource. Yes.

Comment: What happens if you ignore this error and run your app ? Is it running well ?

Comment: Yes. It runs well.

Comment: Then better ignoring such errors, The code is not compiled during design time, So that these kind of error is shown in preview pane.

Comment: But without running the application in emulator or physical device it is not possible to see the layout view in Design mode. So everytime I have to run the project.Its time consuming.

Comment: Can you show layout ?

Comment: Here is the code snippet  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

Comment: Are you sure there is an app_bar layout exist ? Your code couldn't find that layout.

Comment: Apps running fine and app bar layout works well.

Comment: Then i think same like @ShreeKrishna

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio 2.2 launch ConstraintLayout for nested layout. Add ConstraintLayout as a main layout for app_bar.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note:- Don't forget to add dependencies for  ConstraintLayout.

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
```